# How can I beat "DOOM: Knee-Deep in the Dead" on nightmare mode?

Tags: doom

So I have the shareware version of DOOM 1.9, and have been playing it for a while now.
I have beaten it (rather easily) on all skill levels except Nightmare. I have gotten past Missions 1 (Hangar) and 2 (Nuclear Plant), but am currently stuck on Mission 3 (Toxin Refinery).

My question is has anyone here beaten *DOOM: Knee-Deep In The Dead* on Nightmare mode and if there are any tips on how I might do so myself?

Comment: Why did you roll your post all the way back...?

Comment: the title was changed to "is it possible to beat Toxin Refinery". That wasn't my question, my question was has anyone beaten the whole game. I was wondering if anyone had done that, not so much specific help on E1M3.

Comment: I'm not sure that that isn't your question ... you've already completed the first two missions on Nightmare, so you probably don't need help with those. Maybe "How can I beat" is better than "Is it possible," but in either case, the third mission seems to be your problem.

Comment: i'm not asking for help on how to (though maybe i should :) in this question. What i was asking is, has anyone done it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've done it.  It took a ton of memorization and preparation to do.  Here are some tips.

1. Memorize the Maps.  Make sure you know where every health pack, weapon, ammo, secret location, and enemy spawn is.
2. Only go where you need to, if you don't need to grab rocket ammo on E1M3, then don't.
3. Rebind your keys in the setup program.  I used W A S D with the Arrow Keys to turn.
4. Circle Strafe... but keep awareness of where you're strafing.
5. Don't waste ammo.  You don't need to use the Rocket Launcher to kill a Sarge, so don't.
6. Learn how to get the enemies to fight each other... this is relatively easy with strafing.  Get between two of them, and if you time it right, one will fire and hit the other as long as you keep moving.  They will then be fighting, and you can move on.
7. Use number 6... a lot.
8. Keep moving at full speed.  If you stop moving, you're dead.
9. Watch speed runs, and use those routes.  The faster you get through a level the higher your chance of success is.

Ultimately, this is one of those feats that will take practice and a lot of failure before you'll be able to achieve it.  It took me about 7 months of practice before I managed it, but it felt oh so sweet after I got through the first and second Episodes.  I still haven't beaten Episode 3: Inferno, on Nightmare.

Comment: IMO you would have a much easier time using WASD, and the mouse to turn. Because it's analog and you can whip your viewpoint around with great speed and precision. The keys are not analog, so you just turn realllllly slowwwwwwly at a constant speed while an imp is frying your bum with fireballs.

Answer (score 16):

Looks easy.

Comment: Holy... that looks impossible to do

Comment: It looks like it took a lot of planning.

Comment: How hard can it be?

Comment: looks like W+M1

Comment: @Thor It's hard enough that when you start a new game with that skill level, there is a prompt that says `"Are you sure? This skill level isn't even remotely fair"`